# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '{' (at editor.js:71:16)

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

im not sure what the issue is but im trying to make a blog editor and the code involves a publish button that post the blog on he website and on firebase but ive run into this problem: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '{' (at editor.js:71:16)

```js
import { initializeApp } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.20.0/firebase-app.js";
import { getFirestore} from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.20.0/firebase-firestore.js";

// Your web app's Firebase configuration
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "i have it in my project file dw",
  authDomain: "the-butler-353f4.firebaseapp.com",
  projectId: "the-butler-353f4",
  storageBucket: "the-butler-353f4.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "804499070225",
  appId: "1:804499070225:web:28bf3f44bf8bc3a38100b0"
};

// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const db = getFirestore(app);

export { app, db };
```

```
const blogTitleField = document.querySelector('.title');
const articleFeild = document.querySelector('.article');

// banner
const bannerImage = document.querySelector('#banner-upload');
const banner = document.querySelector(".banner");
let bannerPath;

const publishBtn = document.querySelector('.publish-btn');
const uploadInput = document.querySelector('#image-upload');

bannerImage.addEventListener('change', () => {
    uploadImage(bannerImage, "banner");
})

uploadInput.addEventListener('change', () => {
    uploadImage(uploadInput, "image");
})

const uploadImage = (uploadFile, uploadType) => {
    const [file] = uploadFile.files;
    if(file && file.type.includes("image")){
        const formdata = new FormData();
        formdata.append('image', file);

        fetch('/upload', {
            method: 'post',
            body: formdata
        }).then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => {
            if(uploadType == "image"){
                addImage(data, file.name);
            } else{
                bannerPath = `${location.origin}/${data}`;
                banner.style.backgroundImage = `url("${bannerPath}")`;
            }
        })
    } else{
        alert("upload Image only");
    }
}

const addImage = (imagepath, alt) => {
    let curPos = articleFeild.selectionStart;
    let textToInsert = `\r![${alt}](${imagepath})\r`;
    articleFeild.value = articleFeild.value.slice(0, curPos) + textToInsert + articleFeild.value.slice(curPos);
}




let months = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"];

publishBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    if(articleFeild.value.length && blogTitleField.value.length){
        // generating id
        let letters = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
        let blogTitle = blogTitleField.value.split(" ").join("-");
        let id = '';
        for(let i = 0; i < 4; i++){
            id += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * letters.length)];
        }

        // setting up docName
        let docName = `${blogTitle}-${id}`;
        let date = new Date(); // for published at info

        //access firstore with db variable;
        const { doc, setDoc } = require("firebase/firestore");     

        import { doc, setDoc } from "firebase/firestore";   71

        const blogRef = doc(db, "blogs", docName);
        const docData = {
          title: blogTitleField.value,
          article: articleFeild.value,
          bannerImage: bannerPath,
          publishedAt: `${date.getDate()} ${months[date.getMonth()]} ${date.getFullYear()}`
        };
        
        setDoc(blogRef, docData)
          .then(() => {
            location.href = `/${docName}`;
          })
          .catch((err) => {
            console.error(err);
          });
        
        
    }
})
```

im making a publish button on a blog site and I don't believe this is an issue with firebase

Comment: can u please show us please what line 71 is in code example?

Comment: @Sysix I’ll edit the code marking it with 71

Comment: move this line on top of your code and remove the line before. You declaring 2 times the variables

Answer (score 0):

Your line 71 shouldn't have an import
`An import declaration can only be used at the top level of a module`

Comment: if i dont use import then what can i use instead

Comment: @P.K ive edited the post and included the firebase config if youd care you have look

Comment: Use a cdn or the require function

Answer (score 0):

If you're running this code in a browser, probably you need to replace your `import` with loading `firestore` from CDN (https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/alt-setup).

Or, in the other hand, you could pack your script along with the `firestore` using webpack.